# why session id is gendered as '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

In my `db` table i have a `PK` column `sessId` of `uniqueidentifier` set with the function `newid()`. But when i insert a record the `sessId` is generated as `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

I thought this was a system error so i ran `select newid()` it generated a new `id`. but why the column gets inserted with those **zeros**?

Comment: How are you inserting the row? If you are using Entity Framework, for instance, you must set the Guid or make it nullable. The default of Guid is all zeros so when it arrives at the database it has a value and the sql default is not used.

Comment: @Crowcoder i use EF saveChanges()

Comment: right, so you must give the field a value or make it nullable: `Guid?`

Comment: @Crowcoder im going through the code to check null was inserted brb

Comment: @Crowcoder EF Assume im using Entity class Session directly. So if the table generates the sessId using newid() it should generate it from db. But i cannot set the SessId in the Entity class to Nullable because i have used DB first. In this case how do i make it nullable?

Comment: I haven't used EF database first since code first was introduced, but I think you can modify the class in some way, in the designer maybe. But you can just give the session id a `Guid.NewGuid()` instead of trying to let the database do it.

Comment: @Crowcoder i cannot tag the question and give marks wihtout posting as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that your SessId field is a Guid which is a value type and therefore must have a default value and that value is all zeros. So when save to the database, there is a value on the field (all zeros) and the database default is not triggered.
You can give SessId a value before calling `SaveChanges()` with `Guid.NewGuid()` and don't rely on the database to do it.
Or, if you can find a way to do it on your entity, make the field a nullable Guid so that it arrives at the database as null.